# Finding the longest string, data type, data type value along with the column name in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and have been trying to figure this out all day.
I am trying to create a SQL query for SQL server to list each column name in the table being queried, the data type of that column, the amount set for that data type (for example: nvarchar(255)), and the longest string in that column all in a single query.

So far I have this:

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(200) = 'Customer'

SELECT column_name AS ColumnName, data_type AS DataType, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS CharacterSetLength, NUMERIC_PRECISION AS NumericSetLength
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name = @Table
ORDER  BY ordinal_position
```

I also have been using MAX(LEN(column_name)) to find the longest string in that column, but I don't think this is the correct way to query for the longest string since I am getting "21" as a result for "date" when the longest date is only 10 characters long: "2017-05-17"

How do I combine these two queries?

What is the correct way to query for the longest string in a column?

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL (or potentially an XML hack.) As for dates, you wouldn't expect to store that in a variable length column anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible from my point of view with one single query. However, you can collect the base data and run your MAX (LEN()) if you cast as NVARCHAR(MAX) before, then the date size will look more realistic - I have made it in a in a loop with a try-catch in case the cast fails. Below is an example (I have used the schema name in case you want to differentiate between tables)

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(255) = 'Customer'
DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(255) = 'dbo'

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @j INT 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @buffer TABLE (buffer_value VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @actual_max_size INT
DECLARE @sch_table_name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @column_name VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @TbList TABLE ( 
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
    sch_name VARCHAR(255),
    table_name VARCHAR(255),
    column_name VARCHAR(255),
    datatype_name VARCHAR(255),
    type_length INT,
    actual_max_size INT )

INSERT INTO @TbList 
(   sch_name ,
    table_name ,
    column_name ,
    datatype_name ,
    type_length )
SELECT 
    s.name AS sch_name,
    t.name AS table_name,
    c.name AS column_name,
    y.name AS datatype_name,
    c.max_length AS type_length
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s
ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
JOIN sys.types y
ON c.user_type_id = y.user_type_id 
WHERE t.name = @Table
AND s.name = @Schema 

SET @i = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM @TbList )
SET @j = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @TbList )
WHILE @i <= @j
BEGIN 
    DELETE FROM @buffer 
    SET @sch_table_name = (SELECT sch_name+'.'+table_name FROM @TbList WHERE id = @i)
    SET @column_name = (SELECT column_name FROM @TbList WHERE id = @i)
    SET @sql = ('SELECT MAX(LEN(CAST ('+@column_name+' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))) FROM '+@sch_table_name+'')
    BEGIN TRY 
        INSERT INTO @buffer (buffer_value) EXEC (@sql) 
        SET @actual_max_size = (SELECT TOP 1 buffer_value FROM @buffer)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH 
        SET @actual_max_size = -1
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
    IF @actual_max_size IS NULL
    BEGIN 
        SET @actual_max_size = 0
    END 
    UPDATE @TbList SET actual_max_size = @actual_max_size WHERE id = @i
    SET @i = @i+1
END 
SELECT * FROM @TbList
```

A few comments: I use a loop to get the MAX LEN of each column one by one. This is not the most elegant approach, but it works fine. It may take some time if the table is big. 
Note: to run the query in a loop we have to make it in dynamic SQL. Then the question is to bring back the output of the dynamic SQL into the main query and update the memory table. This is possible with sp_executesql, but I find it faster with my solution above:
My solution is based on the principle that we can insert the output of a dynamic SQL query into a table. I then create a buffer table to store the result of the query, and I update the variable with a select top 1 from that buffer table (Which is emptied at the start of the loop). Not perfectly elegant but works OK.

Comment: Any chance you have this Answer for use with MySQL V 5.6.nn or newer that you could/would post?